# A/C Fan Does Not Turn Occasionally on 2018 Jeep Grand Cherokee

Tags: ac, jeep, fan, heater-blower

Every once and awhile my A/C fans don't turn on in my Jeep. I'll turn off the A/C and turn it back on, adjust fan speed, and they still don't turn on. I'll turn off the car and turn it back on with no luck. But then, I leave my Jeep off overnight and in the morning the fans will work again.

Is this an easy fix or something I would need to bring into a shop for?

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be diagnosed. You need to test power supply to the blower motor when the fault is present. If there's power to motor the motor needs replaced. If not you need to check wiring heater control module and BCM. If you aren't confident in DIY for any of these then the answer to your question is you need to bring it to the shop.